# Why doesn't my objdump -D of program look different from .S

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, objdump, disassembly

I am learning the toolchains for my C++ and trying out the objdump.

The disassembled file from objdump doesn't even have the word "Hello World". Why is that? Is it not reliable at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) { printf("Hello world\n"); }
```

can be completely disassembled with `objdump -Dslx my_prog`, which reveals, amongst other things, the following:

```
Contents of section .rodata:
 400598 01000200 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
 4005a8 48656c6c 6f20776f 726c6400           Hello world.
```

If yours is different, then please post code, etc.